# Tuleap - Queries

Tags: artifacts, tuleap

Is it possible to automatically close a bug after 48 hrs, when it status is fixed, because sometimes the user might not(or forget) to close the ticket when the bug was fixed.
Is it possible to send a escalation mail to the team members, when the ticket was unattended for certain number of hrs.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, no. The only similar thing is the Date Reminder in the mail notification settings.

You could have a date field "Fix date", a post-transition rule that set the date when setting the artefact to "fixed", and a date reminder 1 day after to check the artifact. Maybe if closing the artifact unset the fix date the mail will not be sent.

It's a quite ugly workaround, but it's the only available for now.

Comment: i did what u said exactly in the post-transition rule, i kept the default value type for date reminder as "NONE" when the ticket state was changed to fixed, it took the current date and time and things went smooth for first 3 days and i have a new problem like, the default value type for fix_date automatically get selected as 'Today' in the field usage section. Hence, when the user rises a new ticket the fix date also get selected along with the start date.

Comment: So now in the field usage you cannot select "none" anymore?

Comment: ya, i can able to select the none, but after 2-3 days again it's automatically get selected as today.